# Optimizing Input Verification in Nested Class Methods

Tags: python, validation, metaclass, class-constructors

I have the following example class:

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def method1(cls, value):
        print(f'method1 called with value: {value}')
        cls.method2(value)
        cls.method3(value)

    @classmethod
    def method2(cls, value):
        print(f'method2 does something with supplied value: {value}')

    @classmethod
    def method3(cls, value):
        print(f'method3 does something with supplied value: {value}')
```

As you can see, there is a nested logic here. `method1` has to call the methods `method2` and `method3`. Now, every time any of the methods (I have many more) is called, I want to verify the input value. I could define a classmethod and then call `cls._verify(cls, value)` at the beginning of each function. However, this will mean that my input will be verified mulitple times.

How can I efficiently perform input verification for a set of class methods, including nested calls, without redundantly verifying the input multiple times?

I tried: (1) I tried adding a "cache" argument (i.e. cls._already_verified) that would be turned to True after verification. The problem with this approach is that the next time another method of my class is runned, the value is still True.
Also, (2) only calling a _verify method in public classes would not work, because many of the methods build on other publicly available method.

Comment: Are you also using _methods? Because if not, why not call `cls._verify(cls, value)` in method1? Then its only called once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the question for clarification: method2 and method3 should also be able to called on their own. adding cls._verify(cls, value) to each method seperatly would thus mean that verification is always performed for each method, but in total 3 time when I would call method one. This is what I would like to prevent.

Comment: HI @mkrieger1, thanks for your reply. Yes I am aware of this approach. However, the thing is that method1 (in this example) builds on the logic in method2, and method2 has at the same time logic functionallity that I also want to have publicly available.

Comment: BTW this is not really specific to class methods. The same problem could arise with normal methods and could be solved in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate the logic of your methods into a public and a private layer. The public layer is responsible for verifying the inputs and otherwise delegates to the private layer, and the private layer trusts that the inputs are already verified and is responsible for the actual application logic.

The private methods can freely call each other without the verification overhead. The public methods should only call private methods after the inputs are verified, but not call other public methods.

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def method1(cls, value):
        print(f'method1 called with value: {value}')
        cls._verify(value)
        cls._method2_no_verify(value)
        cls._method3_no_verify(value)

    @classmethod
    def method2(cls, value):
        cls._verify(value)
        cls._method2_no_verify(value)

    @classmethod
    def method3(cls, value):
        cls._verify(value)
        cls._method3_no_verify(value)

    @classmethod
    def _method2_no_verify(cls, value):
        print(f'method2 does something with supplied value: {value}')

    @classmethod
    def _method3_no_verify(cls, value):
        print(f'method3 does something with supplied value: {value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra parameter that indicates whether `value` has already been verified.

```
class MyClass:
    @classmethod
    def method1(cls, value, verified=False):
        if not verified:
            cls._verify(value)
        print(f'method1 called with value: {value}')
        cls.method2(value, verified=True)
        cls.method3(value, verified=True)

    @classmethod
    def method2(cls, value, verified=False):
        if not verified:
            cls._verify(value)
        print(f'method2 does something with supplied value: {value}')

    @classmethod
    def method3(cls, value, verified=False):
        if not verified:
            cls._verify(value)
        print(f'method3 does something with supplied value: {value}')
```

Comment: I have thought about indeed storing a flag cls._verify class argument that would serve as a cache that would check wether the method cls._verify() has already been runned (I assume this was somewhat what you were referring to). The problem is that this would mean that the next time another method is runned, the cls_verify is still True, while a new method is called.

Comment: Right, it has to be specific to that call, it can't be a class-wide flag.